# Could anyone tell from the Manifest why my app is not supported on Droid X?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Users report that my app is not supported on their Droid X phones. The manifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="xxxx"
      android:versionName="1.4"
      android:installLocation="auto" 
      android:versionCode="14">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <uses-configuration android:reqFiveWayNav="false"
                        android:reqHardKeyboard="false"
                        android:reqKeyboardType="undefined"
                        android:reqNavigation="nonav"
                        android:reqTouchScreen="notouch"></uses-configuration>

    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Main"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I really do not understand why it is not supported because it's a very simple app and I do not find anything odd in the Manifest file.

Could the fault be on users' phones instead of inside of my app? Any suggestions?

**--- EDIT ---**

My other apps do not have attributes `uses.configuration` and `supports-screen` and they DO NOT produce such error (users did not report any such).

Could the problem be in these attributes?

Comment: Your manifest seems fine to me .Just a question : What's the total size of your apk file ?

Comment: Size of APK is less than 1MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a problem in

> My other apps do not have attributes **uses.configuration** and
>   **supports-screen** and they DO NOT produce such error (users did not
>   report any such).

Once I removed these attributes, the app became supported on all devices.

Anyone knows why? I will wait a couple of days before opening a separate topic on this issue and link it here.

Answer (score 0):

Some droid phones has this error 18 when installing or updating some apps . It's caused by smdl2tmp . You will see this log line : Failed to create secure container smdl2tmp

The solution is to manually delete smdl2temp1 file. 
The file is likely to reside in 2 locations:

1. /sdcard/.android_secure: this is an invisible folder on your SD card, which you can access with any file manager(No root needed)
2. /mnt/secure/asec/: access to this folder requires root and a program like root explorer

I hope it would help .

Comment: When you say log line, do you mean Market Errors page or debugger log cat message?

Comment: Do you know if HTC Glacier may have the same issue as 1 user applied the same error as well???

Comment: Sorry , I've meant logcat logs . Any droid phone may have this error especially when the internal memory is almost full .

Comment: Thanks but it's impossible to have those logs from users' phones :). The problem is that I myself never got such error and that's why I was confused. Is there anything I (as developer) can do or the only solution is to put warning in the description of Android app on the Market?

Comment: I understand and I'm confused as well , for the issue with smdl2temp1 I had it personally on a Motorolla droid a long time ago and I solved it with the delete procedure . As a developer without logs it's really hard to tell . Sorry I can't help that much :( Can you look for a Moto droid phone and try to reproduce the error ?